GDAL - From jp2 image with rpc file to Orthophoto geotiff and keep the image rotation
We are trying to convert a jp2 image with rpc to orthoPhoto geo tiff. We do the following process. The problem is that in the ortho.tiff file the image don't preserve it's rotation angle from the jp2 image. This is our code (using cmd).
How do we preserve the angle?
gdal_translate -of GTIFF -gcp 0.500000 0.500000 lang1 lat1 -gcp 30199.500000 0.500000 lang2 lat2 -gcp 30199.500000 40182.500000 lang3 lat3 -gcp 0.500000 40182.500000 lang4 lat4 -a_srs EPSG:4326 C:\todelete2\1\orthogeotiff\1.jp2 C:\todelete2\1\orthogeotiff\1_gcp.tif

gdalwarp -of GTiff -tps -tr 30200 40183 -t_srs EPSG:4326 C:\todelete2\1\orthogeotiff\1_gcp.tif C:\todelete2\1\orthogeotiff\1_orthoPhoto.tif


With rpc you mean rational polynomial coefficients https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc22_rpc.html, right?

@user30184
yes.
